# HttpClient - two timeouts for large uploads

Tags: http, upload, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using .net HttpClient but this may be a more general question about HTTP:
I want to allow users to upload large files, from sometimes slow and unreliable mobile connections.
If the upload doesn't start within, say, 20 seconds, there's probably a connection problem, so the app should take appropriate action (eg give up for now and try again later.)
But if the upload starts, it might take several minutes to complete. In this case I don't want a timeout to interrupt it. I then only want to give up and throw an error if the upload progress speed slows to a crawl.

So it seems like I want two timeout conditions - a 20 second timeout for the initial connection, and a 10 minute (or preferably dynamically computed) timeout for upload completion.

Is there a way to do this? HttpClient.Timeout seems to set a limit on the entire upload, not just the initial connection.

I'm using HttpClient.PutAsync(), and I'm monitoring progress by overriding HttpContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(). If necessary I could just include a minimum speed check in this function to terminate if progress is too slow.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Timeout on HttpClient is not going to be useful for you.  As far as I can tell there is no way to distinguish between the connection timeframe and sending the request body.

Your best option is to create your own derived HttpContent as you suggested, or maybe using PushStreamContent.  That would allow you to monitor the send progress.

Assuming your server doesn't return connection:close you could hit the server with a HEAD request that opens the TCP connection and then your second request can be the PUT and it will re-use the TCP connection.  At least that way you know the server is available.

Comment: But, for some unknown reason, none of the PutAsync overloads take HttpCompletionOption. Does this mean I need to use SendAsync instead? How would I do that? I can't find an example using the HttpClient methodology.

Comment: So in your code above, how do I then use the response variable to perform the actual upload? (with progress reporting). The methods I used with WebRequest or HttpClient.PutAsync don't seem applicable in this case.

Comment: @thund I added an update, hopefully that is enough details to get you going.

Comment: But response.Content is an HttpContent, which doesn't have a GetStreamAsync(). It has a ReadAsStreamAsync(), but that gives a non-writable stream, so I can't use it to upload anything.

Comment: @thund Oh sorry for confusing the issue.  I completely missed your point about the large file being on the upload.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Right, I'd wondered about doing two hits on the server. Seems awfully hackish though. That seems to be a common theme, unfortunately: If I want uploads and downloads that are non-blocking, progress-reporting, and robust, I seem to need to build them myself. I'd naively hoped HttpClient might actually provide adequate built-in functionality for "fast and fluid" apps.

Comment: @thund The problem is that the current implementation of HttpClient is only a wrapper around the existing HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse classes.  We need a new HttpClientHandler implementation to do be able to do a better job.

Comment: @thund At least with HttpClient you could create your own intermediary handler that does the "is it alive" poke and it would become transparent to your client code.